# Please help me interpreting Elementary Set Theory question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove something for homework, but I can not for the life of me figure out what the theorem I'm supposed to prove is. Again, please: I am not asking for you to prove it for me (that's my hw and I want to do it myself), I am just asking you to help me understand what it is that I am trying to prove here.

What is  this "theorem like 1.1.5 for the intersection and union of A" which I am supposed to prove?

[image: screencap of my problem]

Comment: In short, Theorem 1.1.5 applies to pairs of sets. They want you to prove the same thing for larger numbers of sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The book is hinting for you to show that
$$
\left(\bigcup_{Y\in\mathcal{A}}Y\right)^{c}=\left(\bigcap_{Y\in\mathcal{A}}Y^{c}\right)
$$
and
$$
\left(\bigcap_{Y\in\mathcal{A}}Y\right)^{c}=\left(\bigcup_{Y\in\mathcal{A}}Y^{c}\right).
$$
Note that when $\mathcal{A}=\left\{ A,B\right\} $ you get back your
original problem.

**Edit**:

1. We define $\bigcup_{Y\in\mathcal{A}}Y$ as the set of all $x\in X$ s.t. $x\in Y$ for some $Y\in\mathcal{A}$.
2. We define $\bigcap_{Y\in\mathcal{A}}Y$ as the set of all $x\in X$ s.t. $x\in Y$ for all $Y\in\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: But it's one of my favourites!

Comment: Very helpful. :) I am familiar with that notation and can take it from here, thanks.^^

Answer (score 4):

The statements (a) and (b) are the so-called De Morgan’s laws for pairs of sets. Very similar statements hold for triplets of sets:

$$(A\cup B\cup C)^c=A^c\cap B^c\cap C^c$$

and $$(A\cap B\cap C)^c=A^c\cup B^c\cup C^c\;.$$

Can you state a similar pair of theorems for not just two or three sets at a time, but for arbitrary collections of sets? Once you actually state the right theorems, proving them won’t be hard.

Comment: This was exactly the help I needed.^^ Thank you!

Comment: @Kurow: You’re welcome!